# Is it possible to set a ranged breakpoint in TRACE32 using symbols?

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, trace32, lauterbach

I'm want to set a ranged breakpoint in the TRACE32 software with symbolic names. The usual syntax is like this
`start--end`
but depenting on my ELF I need a dynamic range like this
`0x00--SYM_NAME`.

Is it possible? When yes, how?

Thx in advanced

---

I use DIAB (now Windriver) compiler for PowerPCs and the TRACE32 version is Aug 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRACE32 differentiates between plain addresses and decorated addresses (=access class + address). Ranges allow the following combination of addresses:

```
<plain address>--<plain address>
<decorated address>--<plain address>
<decorated address>--<decorated address>
```

If you want to use debug symbol as range end, you have two choices: Either convert the debug symbol into a plain address or make sure that the first address is decorated as well. The second option is not recommended, as it requires to know which access class to use.

```
Break.Set 0x0--(ADDRESS.OFFSET(my_func)-1)
Break.Set P:0x0--(my_func-1)
```

Another alternative to get the desired range may be to use the section information, e.g. to set a breakpoint range on the whole .text section:

```
Break.Set sYmbol.SECPRANGE(\\my_program\.text)
```

Or from begin of a section up to a certain function:

```
Break.Set sYmbol.SECADDRESS(\\my_program\.text)--(sYmbol.BEGIN(my_func)-1)
```